# QML: How to move an object from a previous set postion using states

Tags: qt, qml

I have an object that I want to move from it's previously set position every time that particular state is set. I've tried making a separate property called xPos to get around the binding loop error which is set by the object's new position of x after the state is set, then entering a default state just to be able to switch back to that specific state again since calling the same state does nothing but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
property int xPos: 0

states: [                                                                       
    State {
        name: "nextStep"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: progressBar_Id
            x: -1*(progressBar_Id.step.width) + xPos
        }
    },
    State {
        name: "previousStep"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: progressBar_Id
            x: progressBar_Id.step.width + xPos
        }
    },
    State {
        name: "default"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: progressBar_Id
            x: xPos
        }
    }
]

transitions: [
    Transition {
        from: "*"
        to: "nextStep"
        NumberAnimation {properties: "x"; easing.type: Easing.Linear; duration: 1000}
        onRunningChanged: {
            if(!running) {
                xPos = progressBar_Id.x;
                console.info("xPos = " + xPos);
                state = "default";
            }
        }
    },
    Transition {
        from: "*"
        to: "previousStep"
        NumberAnimation {properties: "x"; easing.type: Easing.Linear; duration: 1000}
        onRunningChanged: {
            if(!running) {
                xPos = progressBar_Id.x;
                console.info("xPos = " + xPos);
                state = "default";
            }
        }
    }
]
```

xPos seems to get set the first time from the console output but never applies the new xCoord to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually came up with a much better alternative using a ListView.

```
ListView {
    id: listView_Id
    width: contentWidth
    height: bubbleSize
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    spacing: 0

    delegate: Item {
        width: bubbleSize
        height: width

        ProgressBubble {
            stateText: stateNumber
            currentState: state
        }
    }
    model: ListModel { id: progressModel_Id }
}
```

Another qml file:

```
progressModel.insert(0, {stateNumber: number++, state: "current"});
```

But I ran into another problem, is there anyway to change a state within a delegate after it's been added to the ListView?

I've already tried progressModel.set and progressModel.setProperty but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly specify the id of the item on which you wish to set the state, e.g:

```
idOfComponent.state = "default"
```

All QML Items and derivatives have a property called `state`, so the code needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

**state** is a property for qml types, so when you are assigning "state" to "currentState" for "ProgressBubble", its taking the value of **state** in which " ProgressBubble" is currently present.

Rename "state" to something else like "presentState" and then try.

Moreover id of ListView model(*progressModel_Id*) and the one used to insert model elements(*progressModel*) in different file are different, both of them must refer to same id.

After these changes, you can try set property of model. Sample code snippet:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 360
    height: 360

    property int number: 1

    ListView {
        id: listView_Id
        width: 100 //contentWidth // this creates property binding issue 
        height: 100 // bubbleSize // I was not sure about this value
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        spacing: 0
        delegate: Item {
            width: 100 // bubbleSize // I was not sure about this value
            height: width
            ProgressBubble {
                state: "default"
                stateText: stateNumber
                currentState: presentState

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        progressModel_Id.set(index,{stateNumber: stateNumber, presentState: "not current"})
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        model: ListModel { id: progressModel_Id }
    }
    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        progressModel_Id.insert(0, {stateNumber: number++, presentState: "current"});
    }
}
```